# Why my node server application stops/ goes to suspended mode when i kill its child process?

Tags: node.js, linux, shell, kill, child-process

I was building an application with node.js as back end, which runs shell scripts inside it.

I have added a feature to stop the execution of script .
For running script I use the exec process in node.

But when I kill the child process created in exec, the application also stops.

Comment: How are you running your node app ? using pm2 ?

Comment: Just by node server.js , where server.js is my app name